# Downloading/installing package from github converting underlying R code

Tags: r, devtools, rlang, tidyeval

I have a private R package on github that I have made.

I make use of `!!rlang::sym(function_argument)` frequently to accept inputs from functions and use with tidyverse.

For example:

```
example_function = function(x){

new = mtcars %>% arrange(desc(!!rlang::sym(x))

return(new)
}
 example_function('mpg')
```

So I have this uploaded to a private github, and then if I go to install it -          `devtools::install_git('myaccount/myrepo')`

when I look at the underlying code in the function

```
myinstalled_package::example_function
```

It shows as **`!(!rlang::sym`** wherever I had `!!rlang::sym`.   The function still actually works, but again, when I examine the code it doesn't.   I looked on github and the code is correct there, it is just when I download it to my computer that I have this really annoying conversion.

I am also seeing other similar changes such as if I had `!!each_var :=` being converted to `:=(!(!each_var),`

Is there anyway to stop this or why this is happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I examine the code it doesn't"?

Comment: See this answer to a similar issue I created: https://github.com/jimhester/lookup/issues/19#issuecomment-339762967

Comment: @Aurèle: Might be worth to paraphrase the solution as a formal answer, so that it can be upvoted and accepted, thus removing the question from the "Unanswered" category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting an [answer by Jim Hester on GitHub](https://github.com/jimhester/lookup/issues/19#issuecomment-339762967):

> The way R code is displayed by lookup is handled solely by R's
>   internal layout code.
>
> It is recommended you install packages with source references by
>   setting `options("keep.source" = TRUE, "keep.source.pkgs" = TRUE)` to
>   ensure source references are available. If they are you will find the
>   output is exactly that in the original source file, e.g.
>
> ```
> > lookup::lookup(dplyr:::rename.data.frame)
> dplyr:::rename.data.frame [S3 method, closure] dataframe.R#L122-125
> function(.data, ...) {
>   vars <- rename_vars(names(.data), !!! quos(...))
>   select_impl(.data, vars)
> }
> <environment: namespace:dplyr>
>
> // c++ source: src/select.cpp#L79-L86
> DataFrame select_impl(DataFrame df, CharacterVector vars) {
>   check_valid_colnames(df);
>   if (is<GroupedDataFrame>(df)) {
>     return select_grouped(GroupedDataFrame(df), SymbolVector(vars), SymbolVector(vars.names()));
>   } else {
>     return select_not_grouped(df, SymbolVector(vars), SymbolVector(vars.names()));
>   }
> }
> ```

So a way to stop this from happening might be `options("keep.source" = TRUE, "keep.source.pkgs" = TRUE)`.